# Does JSP tag libraries work like some kind of tempated JAVA code generation?

Tags: jsp, tags, jstl, jsp-tags

(This question is more about how a container includes a tag. And less about how a tag should be implemented. Thanks *Ravi Thapliyal* for pointing it out.)

I am new to JSP. I learned that JSP pages are finally turned into Servlets.

So I compared the JSP page using some JSTL tags and the servlet Java code generated by the container.

It seems each tag encapsulates a commonly used Java code block with some slots filled/controlled by the tag attributes. And the block is inserted into the `_jspService()` method.

Is this the general mechanism how tag library contributes to the final servlet Java code?

### ADD 1

I dig the generated **servlet** code for a JSP containing `<c:forEach>` tag.

The JSP code is this:

**Picture 1:**

[image]

The generated servlet code is this:

**Picture 2:**

[image]

And

**Picture 3:**

[image]

It should be a **2-step** process to generate the final response to client:

1. `JSP (picture 1) ==> Servlet Java code (picture 2, 3)`
2. `Servlet Java code ==> HTML` (Container execute the `_jspService()` method).

My questions are:

- Where does the code of picture 2 and 3 come from?
- And who layout the code of picture 2 and 3 in the servlet class generated from the JSP?

### ADD 2

By checking the code in picture 3 and for the `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag` class,
I guess the `ForEachTag` type is kind of like an `iterator`:

- It is given a collection of items to iterate through.
- It provides some APIs for external world to control the iteration process.

And to expose the iterated data:

- It use a `scope` as a bridge to convey the current iterated item to the external world.

While the outside `_jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0` method just use the `ForEachTag` type to carry out iteration. Until `ForEachTag` tells him to stop.

So I guess the code in Picture 2 and 3 are just part of the Web Container's JSP parsing logic which are used to support the JSTL tags.

### ADD 3

If my analysis about the different responsibility between Web Container and Tab library, how does a container know how to generate code similar to picture 2 and 3 to support **a new tag library**?

### To answer ADD 3

Be it a simple/classic tag, **Container only NEEDs to generate boilplate code to invoke their lifecycle methods**. Below is an example of a simple tag:

[image]

Container only cares about the lifecycle methods. And if there's body, container will further parse the body for the classic tag. For simple tag, the `doTag()` method covers everything.

### ADD 4

After learning the `classic tag lifecycle`, I understand that `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag` is a classic tag handler. The code in picture 3 is the Container invoking the classic lifecycle methods while evaluating the tag body.

The `ForEachTag`:

- contains the collection data to loop
- maintains the loop status
- and use its lifecycle methods to control the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your observations are correct. A tag library behaves like a mini templating engine running Java code (as part of the final servlet) with tag attributes (optionally) customizing the Java implementation.

If you take a look at your JSP file header, that's using any JSTL tags, you'll notice that it imports a tag library descriptor by referencing its URI and assigns it a prefix used later when invoking one of the tags from the library.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

The URI is mapped (by the conatiner) to a `.tld` Tag Library Descriptor file that contains `<tag>` entries mapping each tag to its implementing Java class and describing all the attributes the tag supports. If you were to implement a custom tag generating an on-screen keyboard, your entry might look like

```
<tag>
  <description>Generates an on-screen keyboard</description>
  <name>onScreenKB</name>
  <tag-class>com.myapp.jsp.tags.OnScreenKBTag</tag-class>
  <body-content>empty</body-content>
</tag>
```

This .tld file is dropped anywhere under the `/WEB-INF` directory. The tag handler class needs to implement a specific *interface* but the container also provides a `SimpleTagSupport` class that we can extend from.

```
public class OnScreenKBTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

  public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    StringBuilder html = new StrinBuilder();
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();

    // tag logic
    html.append(...);
    ...
    // print response
    out.print(html);
  }
}
```

Then in your JSP file you would import

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tags/myapp.tld" prefix="app" %>
```

and use your custom tag as

```
<div id="keyboard">
  <app:onScreenKB />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  In your `onScreenKB` example, the `doTag()` method directly spits content to the final HTML response. It's kind of *HTML templating*. But for tags such as `<jsp:forEach>`, I think their `doTag()` methods should generate some Java code for the final servlet. I am not sure about this since I haven't learned how to write custom tag.

Comment: For tags like `forEach`, the tld `<tag>` would specify `<body-content>` as `scriptless`. That let's your `doTag()` implementation invoke `getJspBody().invoke()` to include the tag body inside a `for` loop implementation. All the Java code would still be encapsulated inside the tag handler class.

Comment: The actual Java code that prints out the html within the tag body is still handled by the container. Your tag handler class does not have to `out.write()` them explicitly.

Comment: the <c:forEach> tag is a `classic` tag, not a `simple` tag.

Comment: I didn't mean `forEach` per se, but tags that would naturally require to iterate over their tag body. But, I see now.. your question is solely focused on how the container includes the tag rather than what the JSP spec says on implementing them. Somehow, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

After learning the classic tag lifecycle, I understand that `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.ForEachTag` is a classic tag handler. The code in picture 3 is the Container invoking the classic lifecycle methods while evaluating the tag body.

The ForEachTag:

- contains the collection data to loop
- maintains the loop status
- and use its lifecycle methods to control the loop.

### To answer ADD 3

Be it a simple/classic tag, **Container only NEEDs to generate boilplate code to invoke their lifecycle methods**. Below is an example of a simple tag:

The red ones are lifecycle methods invoking.

[image]

Container only cares about the lifecycle methods. And if there's body, container will further parse the body for the classic tag. For simple tag, the `doTag()` method covers everything.